# Can a deleted feature be restored with the Powershell Uninstall-WindowsFeature -Remove command?

Tags: powershell, iis, installation, uninstallation

To install a clean iis web-server, I deleted the web-server/iis on the Windows 2019 server with the following command.

```
Uninstall-WindowsFeature -Remove Web-Server
```

Then I deleted the "c:\inetpub" directory, deleted the "%windir%\system32\inetsrv" directory.

Now I want to install iis again I will run my classic asp files. But when I enter Add role, there is only IIS Management Console option under web server.

Comment: Hi omerix! This question is better suited for [sf] than SO. The short answer is that `-Remove` removes it from disk. You need installation media to get it back.

Comment: Have you tried with the command `Install-WindowsFeature Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools` ?